# How do I make async cache-on-top-of-database query-with-update using vertx3

Tags: java, mongodb, caching, asynchronous, vert.x

Below is an illustration on how an in-memory cache can be used on top of a database, using async `vertx-mongo-client`. It's made as minimalistic as possible. It is fully executable, with the important stuff at the top.

Unfortunately there's nothing there to prevent multiple database accesses and cache insertions for the same key, *while the cache entry is established*. Using standard locking mechanisms is out of the question because it would block the event loop.

I need an async cache-and-database call, so that the `cache.get()` calls, subsequent to the first call that will actually hit the db, will 'return to the event-loop' (can I say that?), 'waiting' for the cache entry to become available. (What a horrible sentence, my apologies..)

How do I achieve that? I was thinking about studying some `vertx` module source code, eg. `vertx-mongo-client`, to learn how it is done. But if somebody is able to provide an answer here, it would be great.

```
package q;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.mongo.MongoClient;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle
{
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject().put("db_name", "example_db"));
    SomeCache cache = new SomeCache();

    vertx.eventBus().consumer("sesame_street", messageHandler -> {
      Integer lookUpKey = Integer.valueOf(messageHandler.body().toString());
      JsonObject result = cache.get(lookUpKey);

      if(result != null) {
        messageHandler.reply(result);
        System.out.println("Was served from cache");
      } else {
        mongoClient.findOne("example_collection", new JsonObject().put("_id", lookUpKey),
                new JsonObject(), resultHandler -> {
                  if(resultHandler.succeeded()) {
                    messageHandler.reply(resultHandler.result());
                    cache.put(lookUpKey, resultHandler.result());
                    System.out.println("Value stored in cache");
                  } else {
                    messageHandler.fail(0xBADC0DE, resultHandler.cause().toString());
                  }
                });
      }
    });
  }

  static class SomeCache
  {
    Map<Integer, JsonObject> elMapa = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(Integer key, JsonObject value) {
      elMapa.put(key, value);
    }

    public JsonObject get(Integer key) {
      return elMapa.get(key);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new ExampleVerticle(), completionHandler -> {
      if(completionHandler.succeeded()) {
        vertx.eventBus().send("sesame_street", 1, replyHandler -> {
          if(replyHandler.succeeded()) {
            //Comment out this println and you'll maybe see 'Value stored in cache' twice in the console output.
            System.out.println("Yes! " + replyHandler.result().body());
            vertx.eventBus().send("sesame_street", 1);
          }
          vertx.close();
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertx has the concept of an `Asynchronous Lock`. This doesn't block, but will call a handler with the lock when's it's been obtained.

Have a look at:

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_cluster_wide_locks
http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/shareddata/Lock.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly I haven't had time to investigate it yet. Maybe in a week or so.